# How to hide navigation default, show on click, how to add class to image & div angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on menu navigation. I have a menu icon I want to add class to it to control it from main css file.

When page loads I want to hide navigation. When I click on icon I want to show navigation. when I mouse out from navigation I should hide. I am in confusion how to call css from which file, where I have to write click event in the app.component.ts or where. I have to do all these things in angular 4.0.

```
Thanks in advance.

    <img src="./assets/menuicon.png" [ngClass]="iconStyle">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" ngHide="Expression">
          <!--<li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>-->
          <!--<li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>-->
          <li><a routerLink="one"><img ng-src="images/icon.png" src="{{image}}"></a></li>
          <li><a routerLink="two">two</a></li>
          <li><a routerLink="three">three</a></li>
          <li><a routerLink="four">four</a></li>
          <li><a routerLink="five">five</a></li>
          <li><a routerLink="six">six</a></li>
        </ul>

export class NavComponent implements OnInit {
name:string;
  show:string;
  constructor() {
   this.name = 'Angular 2 Ng Class';
    this.show = "true";
   }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
  logout(){
    this.show = "true";
  }
}
```

Comment: have you tried with bootstrap

Comment: no cant we do it in angular 4.0

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i Misunderstood the Question Here is a Working Plunker for the Same .

https://plnkr.co/edit/ZHd0Ora2fM5rC70GDUMu?p=preview

Template

```
<button (click)="logout()">XXXX</button>

  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" [ngClass]="(show ==='true')?'hide-it':'show-it'">
      <!--<li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>-->
      <!--<li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>-->
      <li><a routerLink="one"><img ng-src="images/icon.png" src="{{image}}"></a></li>
      <li><a routerLink="two">two</a></li>
      <li><a routerLink="three">three</a></li>
      <li><a routerLink="four">four</a></li>
      <li><a routerLink="five">five</a></li>
      <li><a routerLink="six">six</a></li>
    </ul>
```

App.ts

```
export class App {
  name:string;
  show:string;
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular 2 Ng Class';
    this.show = "true";
   }
  logout(){
    this.show = "false";
  }

}
```

CSS

```
.show-it {
  visibility: visible;
}

.hide-it {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: iam getting error AppComponent cannot be used as an entry component. my menu icon is in index.html for navigation i created saparate component my partial pages are working good. i want default hide menu on click show and add a class to icon

Comment: Did you define it in deceleration array of app module

Comment: yes i declared in app.module.ts  like this import {
    Directive,
    HostListener,
    HostBinding
} from '@angular/core'; should i add in ngmodule also can u give me syntax

Comment: i changed some elements now here is no error but menu should be hide default

Comment: Which classes are you usig in this example i have used bootstrap u might need to change few css if you are using differently

Comment: i don't have dropdown menu i just have horizantal menu and my menu icon in the index.html and navigation other component

Comment: app.ts means app.module.ts?

Comment: No it  is the app component. Find the plunker attached

Comment: did you define the css files i defined in the plunker

Comment: i have main.ts i don't have app.js this is angular cli 4.0

Comment: What does it have to do with app.ts . Add the ngclass directive to the component where this nav bar is placed and then ads the variables in its ts files done

Comment: addes like [ngclass]="(show ==='true')?'hide-it':'show-it'"

Comment: Yes and also donot forget to add css classes

Comment: added show-it hide-it in style.css confusion in .ts file please give me syntax

Comment: The syntax is in plunker just copy the whole bav bar with the syntax or if you have team viewer can check tomorrow

Comment: No Rahul i want to add class to my icon and toggle the menu on click menu is hide now on click not showing menu

Comment: sorry rahul not allowed in my company laptop i copy and past in the post again