# How to set a ngStyle in angular 2 if condition matches

Tags: angular

I need to set a style depending on whether or not a value is true.
I need something like this:

```
 <div class="container" [ngStyle]="{ is_root_node: 'box-shadow: none;'}">
     <div class="toolbar-container"></div>
 <div/>
```

but I can't find it in the [documentation for NgStyle](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle)

Comment: possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/45015785/2708210

Comment: @RahulSingh Why don't you flag the question if you think it's a duplicate? You can do it by pressing the flag button under the question.

Comment: @echonax the answer is not upvoted so i coudnt

Comment: That question is completely different from this, the other OP was talking about ngClass not ngStyle

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So, you want to set the `box-shadow` style as `'none'` when `is_root_node` is `true` and don't set it at all otherwise?

Options:

```html
Direct binding:
<div class="container" [style.box-shadow]="is_root_node && 'none'">

<div class="container" [style.box-shadow]="is_root_node ? 'none' : null">

Through NgStyle:
<div class="container" [ngStyle]="{'box-shadow': is_root_node && 'none'}">

<div class="container" [ngStyle]="{'box-shadow': is_root_node ? 'none' : null}">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
<div [ngStyle]="{'box-shadow': 'is_root_node? none : 10px 10px 5px #888888'}"></div>
```